# Create a (edit) hyperlink in front of dropdownbox with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, editing

I have a table with some data. All data is contained in dropdownboxes and textbox. But it isn't easy to see, what is newly written input and what is data from the database.

So I want to create a (edit) after these boxes, and replace the boxes with a literal where the contained value in the dropdownbox stands. When the edit-button is pushed the literal goes away and the dropdownbox appears instead, so it is possible to edit the data. This is all, the jQuery don't have to save the data to database, I have functionality to that in a save-button.

I don't want to use any extra plugin to jQuery, because it seems to be a fairly simpel task.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thw whole code i cant write here, change as your wish.I didn't clear your question.
try this 
when click edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".edit").click(){
 $(".dropdown").show("slow");
 $(".edit").hide("slow");
 });
```

stylesheet.css

```
.dropdown
{
display:none;
}
```

after edit just reverse the code;

Comment: I don't want to show all elements, when the edit-button is clicked. I only want to show the element beside the (edit). But thank you for your answer